# python decorator above something other than def

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

The usual construct for a decorator in python is

```
@decorator
def function(x):
    <code here>
```

which is equivalent to

```
def function(x):
    <code here>
function = decorator(function)
```

(At least, this is my understanding.) Now suppose we are given a function `mystery_func` which we didn't define ourselves but we'd still like to decorate with `decorator`. Can we do

```
@decorator
mystery_func
```

or do we have to do

```
mystery_func = decorator(mystery_func)
```

to get the same effect as

```
@decorator
def mystery_func(args):
    <code here>
```

Comment: This didn't require a question, you could have just tested this in an interactive interpreter in less time than it took to compose the question.

Comment: In case you don't have a Python installation, [Ideone](http://ideone.com/) is good for non-interactive tests, and [PythonAnywhere's "Try IPython" online thing](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/try-ipython/) gives you an online IPython environment, which is usually even better than a regular interactive Python interpreter.

Comment: @ShadowRanger It is still a valid question, perhaps the `OP` didn't know about `class` decorators which is something other than `def`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no, the `@` syntax cannot be used with arbitrary lines, you need to use `mystery_func = decorator(mystery_func)`. Using the `@` syntax like this is a `SyntaxError`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [class decorators](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3129/) which is "something other than def":

eg.

```
@foo
@bar
class A:
  pass
```

But what you mentioned here:

```
@decorator
mystery_func
```

is a `SyntaxError`